# .NET 6 source generator - create classes within another project

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-generation, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I have 3 projects

```
Project A (Client)
Project B (Server)
Project C (Shared)
```

Within Project B I have the DB connection using the entity framework as well as all the entity classes, Project A (Client) should have **no** access to Project B (Server). I want to rely heavily on DTOs for the client/server communication. These DTOs should be created in Project C so both client and server can use them. The source generators are perfect for the generation of the dtos, but is it possible for a source generator to use the entity classes from Project B to generate DTOs in Project C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only generate things for the *current* project being built, but as long as you have *visibility* of the types you need via a reference, you can still access the info *from* the other project.
The `GeneratorExecutionContext` has `context.Compilation.References`, which gives you all the `MetadataReference` hooks. This is high-level, but you can use `context.Compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol(MetadataReference)`, which gives you the root of the type-model for each reference; from *there*, you can inspect all the types along with their properties, attributes, etc - presumably to generate your DTOs.

However, I wonder if it is easier / preferable to be explicit, and do something explicit in `B` such as:

```cs
[module:GenerateDtoWhateverFor(typeof(B.Foo))]
[module:GenerateDtoWhateverFor(typeof(B.Bar))]
// etc
```

and detect / respond to *that*.